# What happens if a transform trigger is copied?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Similarly to my previous question, [what happens when a miracle trigger is copied?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/12359/what-happens-when-a-miracle-trigger-is-copied), Strionic Resonator, a new card printed in Magic 2014 could also be used to copy a transform trigger such as on [Huntmaster of the fells](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bHuntmaster%20of%20the%20fells%5d).

**What happens when this trigger is copied?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If multiple transform abilities are on the stack for the same object, it will simply transform back and forth on each resolved trigger.**

This one is pretty straightforward. It's the same object, and a transform simply flips the switch, no matter which side is currently on top, because Transform is not specific to either side.

The only ruling on [Bloodline Keeper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bloodline%20Keeper) fully applies here.